# gRPC C++ Async Client: Understanding threading

Tags: c++, grpc

Since I couldn't find any answer, I am posting it, In gRPC async client, are threads spawned automatically when request is generated or thread creation has to be done manually for each request?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at an [example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.32.0/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_client2.cc).

In the Async completion queue based model, the application is responsible for creating and managing the threads on their own, and the application then provides these threads to gRPC through the completion queue's `Next()` method to drive the internal polling engine so that work can be done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So if I go with synchronous client there are still threads internally right? So can there be multiple outstanding requests?

Comment: On the client side, gRPC does have internal threads but they might not poll the fds as frequently as you want. With a synchronous model, the application still provides threads to gRPC when an operation is performed, and the function only returns when the operation is deemed to be complete.